# EXCEL VBA find max date and filter x days before max date

Tags: excel, vba, date, filter

I have excel sheet with dates in column A, and I need to find latest date and filter last 7 days before that latest date.
I only found vba codes online which takes todays date - 7 days but I cant use that because these dates are from last year.

Please and thank you!

EDIT:

Thanks for your suggestion.
I tried to put it in my vba code but it filters 0 results.

```
Sub Filter()
    Dim maxDate As Date
    maxDate = WorksheetFunction.Max(ActiveSheet.Range("A:A"))
    ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        ">" & maxDate - 6
End Sub
```

Doesn't work since this VBA macro filers date by dd.mm.yyyy.  (NOTE THE DOT at the end), 0 results in my case, it should filter by dd.mm.yyyy (without dot). I dont know how to filter without dot

EDIT2: This worked for me.

```
Sub Largest()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim dblMax As Double
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A")
    dblMax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(rng)
    ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
            ">" & dblMax - 7, Operator:=xlAnd
End Sub
```

Comment: FYI - You can take a date and "do math" on it, if you have `5/30/2018` in `A1`, in `B1` you can type `=A1-5` to get `5/25/2018`.

Comment: Yes, dates can be tricky with Excel VBA AutoFilter. Some find it easier to just loop through the array to be filtered. Sometimes I have found that one can use the numeric value of the date, as you did when coercing the date to a `Double`

Comment: Instead of "this worked for me" why not post your own Answer to this Question so this is a complete Q&A for others?

Answer (score 2):

To get the max value in a Range (and a column *is* a Range) in VBA, use `worksheetFunction.Max`, eg

```
Dim maxDate as Date
maxDate = worksheetFunction.Max(ActiveSheet.Range("A:A"))
```

Be careful to select a Range with consistent data, so don't mix up dates and numbers.

From there, you can simply subtract 7 from your date (or use `DateAdd(d, -7, maxDate)` and go ahead with the code you already found.

**Edit**: To use the date as filter value, change the data type of `maxDate` to 
`Double`. You can check this by set your filter manually and enter the following statement in the *immediate window* (Ctrl+G):

```
? ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Filters(1).Criteria1
```

This results in (value will be different for you) `>43329`. Background is that Excel/VBA stores dates as `Double`.